# Session variable in ASP.NET Core 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, session-variables, asp.net-core-3.0

I using ASP.NET Core 3.0 MVC, and I heard about data type called Session["value"] in MVC which can be used to transfer information from action to action, even in new requests.

I tried to use it in MVC Core, and I noticed it doesn`t exist.
How can I use this kind of variable?

I would be glad if you could show me an example to write and read this variable.

Comment: Maybe there https://benjii.me/2016/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnetcore-and-mvc-core/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#session-state

Comment: Session variables are well documented. Check [Session and app state in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: It's often faster to go through the Getting Started and [tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) section in the docs and [the available courses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-razor-pages-aspnet-core/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) than trying things at random.

Comment: Don't just run off and session all the things. The way you worded the question implies that you both don't understand how sessions work and that you believe them to be some magic wand that's going to solve some problem you have that probably shouldn't actually be handled with sessions. HTTP is a stateless protocol for a reason. Sessions, which add a layer of state, should be avoided except when absolutely necessary.

Comment: I decided in the end not to use this variable